# Не отображается background-image. Как сделать адаптивный текст внутри адаптивного фона

Tags: html, css, текст, адаптивность, background-image

Я хочу поместить все имеющиеся элементы текста внутрь фона так, чтобы они были адаптивными, как и сам фон. Я решил использовать фон(background-image) вместо картинки для того, чтобы все элементы текста были внутри фона и при изменении размера ширины сайта, или его масштаба всё стояло на своих местах(полностью адаптивный фон, который бы подстраивался под любые размеры, текст чтобы никуда не съезжал и сохранял свои размеры при изменении размера сайта при этом находился внутри фона.

Вот как должно все выглядеть при любых размерах сайта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь я использовал картинку, а не фон.
Элементам текста я задал position: absolute
Все выглядит неплохо, если не изменять ширину или масштаб сайта
А так, если например поменять масштаб получается вот это
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Здесь масштаб 50%. И все пошло по *****

Я уже долго ломаю голову, как все это можно уместить. Буду очень благодарен и признателен за ответ!!!

HTML код:

```
<main> 
        <div class="Block_image"><div class="FLRBK2_img">
        <h1 class="MainText"><span>Always Be <br> Powerfull <br> for new <br> wins</span> </h1>

        <div class="ReadMore">
            <p>Read More</p>
            <div id="RArrow" style="background-image: url(../Images/Adidas/right_arrow.png);"></div>
        </div> 

        <div class="AboutRBK">
            <p id="NameFlorens">Florens RBK <span>2</span></p>
            <p id="Property">New comfortable material for new wins</p>
            <button id="Buy"><p>By Now</p></button>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div> 
</main>
```

CSS код:

```
.Block_image {
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.FLRBK2_img {
  background-image: url(../Images/Adidas/Florens_RBK2.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.MainText span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  top: 130px;
  left: 240px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Anton", cursive;
  font-size: 4.79vw;
  color: rgba(14, 14, 14, 0.7);
  text-shadow: 1px 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

.ReadMore {
  position: absolute;
}

.ReadMore #RArrow {
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.ReadMore {
  left: 78%;
  top: 146px;
}

.ReadMore p {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "PT Sans Caption";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.45vw;
  color: #000000;
  text-shadow: 1px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.ReadMore p:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.ReadMore p:active {
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.AboutRBK {
  left: 70%;
  top: 650px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

.AboutRBK #NameFlorens {
  font-family: Anton;
  font-size: 64px;
  line-height: 94px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0px 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  right: 50px;
}

#Property {
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-family: "PT Sans Caption";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

#Buy {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: none;
  width: 165px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
          box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  cursor: pointer;
}

#Buy p {
  font-family: "Anton";
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #000000;
}

#Buy:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#Buy:active {
  background-color: black;
}

#Buy p:active {
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: обернуть картинку и текст в один блок, картинку на фон этого блока поставить и относительно блока позиционировать текст

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас сайт резиновый, или есть диапазоны адаптива где сайт резинится, то все плохо. Ваша задача сводится к тому, что размер шрифта зависит от ширины страницы и вообще говоря это совершенно разные вещи и связать их довольно таки не просто.

Можете попробовать связать font-size с шириной страницы используя единицы **vw**. Как-то так (значения и формула чисто для примера):

```
h1 {
  font-size: calc(30px + 100vw/5);
}
```

Больше деталей, например тут:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fluid-typography/

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо обернуть картинку и текст в один блок, картинку на фон этого блока поставить и относительно блока позиционировать текст.
А на определенных разрешениях менять размер текста/отступы/положение и т.д.

```css
*{margin: 0;padding:0;box-sizing: border-box;}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.block {
  margin: 25px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #ffbb00 url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556888020-139220bbf85d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1351&q=80) no-repeat center center;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block background">
  <h1>
    <span>Always Be <br> Powerfull <br> for new <br> wins</span> 
  </h1>
</div>
```